# How to do a knock knock test on a telegram bot

Tags: telegram

I have a set of telegram bots that are running 24/7 but I'd like to make sure they are actually responding.  How could I write something that would send something like "knock, knock" and get back a "Who's there?" response to monitor the health of the bots.

I can't use another bot to do this work because bots are not allowed to talk to one another.  So, how do I pull this off?

I'd prefer it be done in python but at this point I'd just like something that could report a status.  My goal is to feed this in `django-healthcheck` custom checker.  I have about 80 bots I need to check with more being added every day or two.

I was thinking I could do it with tdlib but the sendMessage API requires a chatID and all I have is a botName.  Also, none of the bots I've connected with on my phone showed up in the tdlib list of contacts.....

Answer (score 0):

You should use a user account and communicate with those bots using an MTProto library, like [Pyrogram](https://pyrogram.org) or [Telethon](https://telethon.dev).

Many people do this by sending a message to the bot with the user account, and waiting for a response, but this is tricky and I do not recommend it. It can risk your account to get banned or face floodwaits if done constantly.

Instead, I recommend your bot to ping a user account every 30 seconds or something around it, and do something like this in your user account code:

```py
from time import time
from typing import Optional

from pyrogram import Client, filters

last_ping: Optional[float] = None

@Client.message_handler(filters.username("@YourBot") & filters.private & ~ filters.reply & filters.regex("^ping$"))
async def update_status():
    global last_ping
    last_ping = time()
```

Comment: This is a good idea, also means my rate limiting code in the bot will prevent the flood problem and my "client" being external to the other app could restart it if things go south pretty easily